# Cant run "npx expo run:ios --device" on my physical device

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Im trying to run this command above to check my application in my physical device, im tretating with push notifications using Expo Push Notifications, thats why i need to run this build in my physical, i dont know what im supposed to do anymore, i already followed all the tips from all the foruns on internet, reset iphone, reset macbook, reset dev mode on iphone, changed cable to connect, change network, all the tips and nothign works...

The build runs normally until get 100%, qhen get 100% this error below appears:

```
✔ Complete 100%
✖ Complete 100%
CommandError: InvalidService: com.apple.debugserver (request: StartService)
Try reconnecting your device. You can also debug service logs with `export DEBUG=expo:xdl:ios:*
```